# How to search a hash for a key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I would like to get a model object that has a hash value containing  a certain key (I don't know the value). Something like this:

```
Model.all(:conditions => ["hashvalue.has_key => ?", key])
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Model.all.find_all{|model| model.hash.has_key?(key)}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I thought I would have to do some impossible SQL!

Comment: @andrew..hi..using `find_all`..is it equivalent to `select` or does it have any advantage in database side...

Comment: @rubyprince: `find_all` is a Ruby method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001487 . Protip: questions end with a question mark, not ellipses.